# SQL Anywhere 16 to SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sqlanywhere

I am using SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase (SybaseToSQL) but I am getting this message:

> Error collecting data. See the inner exception for details.

Below is the details of my error:

> ERROR [42S02] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Table 'syscharsets' 
>   not found. [Collector: Error] [6696/9] : Exception: ERROR [42S02] 
>   [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Table 'syscharsets' not found
>
> [Gui: Error] [6696/9] : LowLevelAdapter.ReadSource : Read Source
>   error: Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.Collectors.CollectorException:
>   Error collecting data. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S02] [Sybase][ODBC
>   Driver][SQL Anywhere]Table 'sysconfigures' not found

When I query all system tables I didn't find any `syscharsets` and `sysconfigures` tables, is it due to version incompatibility of my `SQL Anywhere`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SybaseToSQL can only be used to migrate ASE (Adaptive Server Enterprise) databases. SQL Anywhere is a separate product and is generally not drop-in compatible with ASE.